# developing office 2003 and office 2007 add-ons with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to develop an Outlook add-on. I must support Office 2003 and office 2007 (not 2010).

Can I do the work on Visual Studio 2010? is it equipped to handle older outlook versions like 2003? or would I have to do the work on VS2005 or VS2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for Office 2003 addons in visual studio 2010, but there is support for 2007 and 2010.

To create a new Outlook project in Visual Studio

Start Visual Studio.

On the File menu, point to New, and then click Project.

In the templates pane, expand Visual C# or Visual Basic, and then expand Office.

Under the expanded Office node, select the 2007 if you have Outlook 2007 installed, or select the 2010 node if you have Outlook 2010 installed.

In the list of project templates, select Outlook 2007 Add-in or Outlook 2010 Add-in.

In the Name box, type FirstOutlookAddIn.

Click OK.